# Facebook share button help

Tags: plugin-development, facebook

I am developing a social sharing widget. It has Facebook sharing option too. I wrote the following link structure for it but when clicked, the page neither displays the link to share, nor the title and decription. Please help out. Thanks

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php get_permalink();?>&t=<?phpthe_title();?>">
Share</a>
```

Comment: Does rest of widget appear? Does anything appear in page source? You are missing space before function call in `<?phpthe_title();?>`

Comment: @Rarst "social widget" = "sidget". Mhm. Learning new things every day. :)

Comment: @Rarst: Thanks for pointing tht out. I fixed that out. The problem is still there :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title( $post_id );
$url = urlencode( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
?>

<a class="fb" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=<?php echo $title; ?>&p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>">Share</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID );?>&t=
<?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID );?>">
Share
</a>
```

I've broken the link up onto separate lines for legibility so you can see what's going on..

Use, `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` and `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` and as Rarst mentioned be mindful of your syntax making sure to put a space between `<?php [and your function call]...etc`

## note

If your widget is outside of the post loop then you will need to pass the Post ID (on single pages, use `get_the_ID()`) to both `get_the_title` and `get_permalnik`.